# LabelEncoder with sklearn , transform and inverse single relationship between values?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Hello and thank you in advance for any tip or advice.

I am working in Python 3.6 with sklearn and DecisionTree Classifier. I use label encoder as my Pandas Dataframe has 4 columns and some are strings.

```
      Origin Duration   Origin Octave  Origin Pitch   Next Pitch
0          quarter           3          B                    G   
1          quarter           4          D                    D   
2          quarter           4          A                    D   
3             16th           4          A                    D
```

Before splitting the dataframe into into training and test sets, I use label encode and a dict to enconde it (tip I read here in StackOverflow, thanks Jon!). The resulting encoded dataframe looks like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(preprocessing.LabelEncoder)
encoded = scoredf.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))


      Origin Duration   Origin Octave  Origin Pitch   Next Pitch
0                 5            1           1                0                
1                 5            2           2                4                 
2                 5            2           0                4                 
3                 0            2           0                4
```

After training and testing the Decision Tree Classifier, I want to pass another dataframe for the model, to obtain predictions.
For example, I want to pass the following DataFrame XX to my model, to obtain the predicition:

```
print(XX)
Origin Duration Origin Octave Origin Pitch
0            zero             5            G
```

I enconded it using the same dict (d = defaultdict(preprocessing.LabelEncoder)), Labelenconding used for the original Dataframe, I use only **"transform"** as I supposed everything is "fitted":

```
XXX = XX.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].transform(x))
```

However the results are incosintents in terms of encoding. I see it gets encoded like:

```
    print(XXX)
           Origin Duration  Origin Octave  Origin Pitch
    0                6              3            10
```

However, following the encoding of the original dataframe used for train and test the model, the resulting data frame should be:

```
            Origin Duration  Origin Octave  Origin Pitch
0                6              3            6
```

So the question is, how to keep the same and consistent LabelEnconding I used for training and testing the  model when I actually used the model to predict afterwards,
This is: How to encode the input dataframe to get predicitions, using the same labels as the one used for training and testing the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can store your original labeling, for instance in a dictionary, and use it for further labeling.

Here is an example referring to the unlabeled df as ´df_orig´ and to the labeled df as ´df_label´. Once you have labelled your dataframe you can build the dictionary.

```
map_dict = dict()

# First level keys are columns names
keys_lvl1 = df_orig.columns

# As values for each column,
# I store a new dictionary corresponding to the labeling 
for k in keys_lvl1:
   keys = df_orig[k]
   values = df_label[k]
   sub_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
   map_dict[k] = sub_dict
```

Later on, you can apply it with

```
# just a copy of the original df for testing purpose
df_label2 = df_orig.copy()

for column in df_label2.columns:
    df_label2[column] = df_label2[column].apply(lambda x: map_dict[column][x])
```

---

**Edit**

This code actually produce consistent result using LabelEncoder with python 2.7. This might help you finding your problem.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
from sklearn import preprocessing
from collections import defaultdict

# Reproducing your dataframe
data = StringIO("""
0    quarter    3    B    G   
1    quarter    4    D    D   
2    quarter    4    A    D   
3    16th     4    A    D
""")

columns = ['col_{}'.format(i) for i in range(4)]
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True, index_col = 0, header=None )
df.columns = columns

print df
```

Returns

```
         col_0  col_1 col_2 col_3
0                            
0  quarter      3     B     G
1  quarter      4     D     D
2  quarter      4     A     D
3     16th      4     A     D
```

Then,

```
# Label encoding
d = defaultdict(preprocessing.LabelEncoder)
df_label = df.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))
print df_label
```

Returns

```
       col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3
0                            
0      1      0      1      1
1      1      1      2      0
2      1      1      0      0
3      0      1      0      0
```

For prediction set, I shuffle the dataframe and drop column 3

```
# Apply to new data
df2 = df.sample(frac=1).drop('col_3', axis=1) # sample(frac=1) shuffles the df
print df2
```

Returns

```
     col_0  col_1 col_2
 0                      
 3     16th      4     A
 1  quarter      4     D
 0  quarter      3     B
 2  quarter      4     A
```

Then,

```
df2_label = df2.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].transform(x))
print df2_label
```

Returns

```
   col_0  col_1  col_2
0                     
3      0      1      0
1      1      1      2
0      1      0      1
2      1      1      0
```

which seems consistent.

Comment: Dear Delforge. Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question and answer. I think you solution would work, as it would basically keep track of the labeling done by LabelEnconder. My only concern,  is not this suppossed to happend automatically and transparent for the user with LabelEncoder Transform and Inverse_transform methods? I mean, once "fitted" transform should be able to handle the conversion transparently, does not it?

Comment: Weird behavior indeed. LabelEncoder seems to work fine when I check it. Are you sure that your test set contains all the existing categorical values? Otherwise, you may also label your set before splitting it between training, test and prediction set.

Comment: Hi Deltaforge, once again thanks for answer. In fact that is what my code does, it encondes with LabelEncoder before calling "train_test_split".

Comment: I added my test with label encoder in my edited post. With this, I am not able to reproduce the problem.